# Найти индекс последнего по счету элемента в массиве, который является меньше среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива

Tags: python

```
a=[int(x) for x in input('Input array:').split()]
n=0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    n+=1
    i+=i
    if (a[i])<i/n):
        print(a[i])
```

ошибка ,хз как исправить,помогите пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте вот так

```
a=[int(x) for x in input('Input array:').split()]
mean = sum(a) / len(a)
index = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] <= mean:
        index = i
        
print(i)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Или `map(int, input('Input array: ').split())`.

Comment: И что когда такой элемент *не существует* (т.е. все элементы равны)?

Comment: @MarianD верно говорите, тогда наверное стоит рассмотреть и ситуацию когда список пустой, а проблема если все елементы равны, видимо выводим последний елемент

a=[int(x) for x in input('Input array:').split()]

while len(a) == 0:
    print('Empty list, repeat enter..')
    a=[int(x) for x in input('Input array:').split()]
    
mean = sum(a) / len(a)
index = None
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] <= mean:
        index = i
        
print(i)

Comment: @Dmitriy, см. [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196495/233990) на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

*«Первые будут последними и последние первыми.» ;-):*

```
import statistics

numbers = [float(x) for x in input('Input array: ').split()]
numbers.reverse()

mean = statistics.mean(numbers) if numbers else 0      # любое число для пустого списка

for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    if number < mean:
        print(len(numbers) - i - 1)
        break
else:
    print("No such number.")
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Функция `enumerate()` занумерует *обратную* последовательность, когда такой индекс существует, выражением `len(numbers) - i - 1` он конвертируется на индекс оригинальной последовательности.

Таким образом *достаточно найти только один подходящий элемент* (команда `break`).

Ветвь `else` команды `break` выполнится тогда и только тогда, когда цикл полностью исчерпался, т.е. когда не встретилась команда `break`.

Answer (score 0):

**первая ошибка**

вы для начала вычислите среднее арифметическое, а потом уже ищите элементы

**вторая ошибка**

```
i/n
```

это не среднее арифметическое :) имеется в виду не среднее от кол-ва элементов, а среднее арифметическое самих элементов - т.е. сначала надо сложить значения всех элементов и потом только разделить на n

**третья ошибка**

в задаче требуется найти индекс, а вы выводите значение элемента

В общем вся задача сделана неправильно

Решение:

```
arr = [*map(int, input('Input array:').split())]

ave = sum(arr) / len(arr)

for i in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
    if arr[i] > ave:
        print(i)
        break
```

можно немного извратиться

```
arr = [*map(int, input('Input array:').split())]

ave = sum(arr) / len(arr)

for obj in reversed([*enumerate(arr)]):
    if obj[1] > ave:
        print(obj[0])
        break
```

Comment: Можешь исправить пожалуйста?

Comment: @Andrij Matviiv, могу, но где именно сложность - алгоритм я описал же

Comment: я хочу немного его упростить прост, чтоб он бил понятен

Comment: @Andrij Matviiv, ловите

Comment: Для `1 1` никакой вывод, для `2 1` вывод 0 (неправильный).

Comment: Зачем такой изврат `[*map`?! Это делается через `list(map` обычно

Comment: @CrazyElf, на 3 символа короче :) `list(map())` конечно лучше выглядит

Comment: @Zhihar Просто лишнее действие получается промежуточное в вашем варианте )  Так то жалко, конечно, что нельзя просто `[map` написать, питон мог бы и сам догадаться, что нам нужно в этом случае ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну это конечно так, то `[map` все таки может быть и 1 элементом списка мэпов, так что все таки лучше оставить как есть :)

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. требуется искать индекс последнего элемента, имеет смысл идти с конца. Вот пример:

```py
a=[int(x) for x in input('Input array:').split()]
index = len(a) - 1
avg = sum(a) / len(a)
for item in reversed(a):
  if(item < avg):
    print(index)
    break
  else:
    index -= 1
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Можно кстати вот так для лаконичности **for item in a[::-1]**

Comment: Для `1 1` никакой вывод, для `2 1` вывод `2` (неправильный, такой индекс не существует).

Comment: Действительно, в моем варианте индексирование начиналось с 1. Исправил. Касаемо `1 1` так и должно быть. В условии задачи мы выводим элемент, который строго меньше среднего арфиметического. `1` не строго меньше `1` поэтому ничего не выводится.

Comment: @AlexeyR., как бы вы, как пользователь вашей программы (не программист) были удовлетворены тем, что программа ничего не выводит?